# drive robot in gazebo ros with Clearpath Husky A200 or other robots

Tags: c++, a200, ubuntu, gazebo-simulator, husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I'm using ROS groovy in my Ubuntu 12.04 and I've installed gazebo under ROS in order to use Husky A200 robot in the virtual environment.

Everything is working good, but I'm not able to understand if I can run my C++ code in my virtual A200 robot under Gazebo without having to physically connect the robot to my USB port.

For example, I have a C++ code which is able to drive the robot along a particular path (forward and backward): can I execute this code under Gazebo and move the virtual robot?

If yes, is there any tutorial I can read to understand how to load my code in gazebo?
Can you help me, please? :)

Thank you a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68152/drive-robot-in-gazebo-ros-with-clearpath-husky-a200-or-other-robots/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2013-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't need to load any code into Gazebo. Your virtual robot (probably) offers exactly the same ROS topics / services as the real one (odom, cmd_vel etc). So, your ROS node can through this topics easily command virtual robot instead of the real one.

---

Originally posted by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) with karma: 704 on 2013-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2013-07-22**:
I posted an answer to better explain my problem by adding also a simple testing code.
Do you think it is possible to run this code in Gazebo? What kind of modifications will I have to do?